# SelectOneMenu update other SelectOneMenu and dynamiccally update a datatable

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, selectonemenu

I have in my jsf page two selectOneMenu and datatable...I want that the first SelectOneMenu update the second selectOneMenu and this latter update the datatable...I can do the first update but even if I change the value of the second selectOneMenu my datatable stay empty.

**Edit:**
I find the source of the problem : in fact the second selectOneMenu is filled with onChange method in the first selectOneMenu (not a getliste ) so when I try to call an other onChange in the second selectOneMenu I can't get the id of the selected items and so my datatable stay empty ... how can I solve this problem I should fill in the second selectOneMenu when the first one has a valid value ??I really nead a solution can someone help me please ?

Comment: Try to give the value `@form` to the ajax tag related to the second selectOneMenu.

Comment: thanks @Omar for your reply I just try this but still doesn't work :\